# Is there a way to match /@user in Apache rewrite rules?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, litespeed

I am trying to redirect users from /@adam to /user/adam on my Litespeed server which uses .htaccess files.

I have already tried the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\/@.+$ /user/$1
```

I expected it to redirect, but it does not. Even tried some variations like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\/@(.+)$ /user/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close!

Do this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^@(.+)$ /user/$1
```

Notice I removed the leading `\/`

If you need to rigorously test htaccess rules then I highly recommend this gem: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/